# How to programmatically get reason for why a script resource failed to load

Tags: javascript, html

I am creating and attaching a `script` tag dynamically in a script. Along with that I am adding an `onerror` handler.
However, when the script fails to load I don't get any details as to why it failed. I would expect some details about script not available (a 404) , or timeout or anything else useful. Any way to get that information ?
Note that I need to get the data programmatically so I can send it to Sentry. It’s for debugging user errors and I may not have access to their browsers and dev tools

```
const newScriptElement = document.createElement('script');
newScriptElement.src = url;
newScriptElement.type = 'text/javascript';
newScriptElement.async = true;
newScriptElement.id = scriptId;
newScriptElement.onerror = (ev) => {
   console.log(ev.message); // <-- The message property doesn't exist. But also no other message like property 
};
document.head.appendChild(newScriptElement);
```

Comment: Check the Network tab of the browser console.

Comment: @tsamridh86 I think we can assume she knows how to open the console, since she's using `console.log()`

Comment: whoops. didn't notice that, removing the comment

Comment: I can see the reason in Network tab , but I’m trying to send the error to Sentry, so need to get it programmatically